# Replacing key value in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

I'm working on a project that is a basic message app. basically i have created an array of objects that allows me to see pre built messages. Then i should be able to click a clear all button and clear all of the messages that are being displayed by looping through the array of objects. this is what i have so far in my messageData.js

```
const messages = [
  {
    id: 'message1',
    message: 'Hello everyone! Welcome to hell',
    userId: 'user1',
  },
  {
    id: 'message2',
    message: 'Yall are weirdos!',
    userId: 'user3',
  },
  {
    id: 'message3',
    message: 'Hey! I think everyone is awesome!',
    userId: 'user2',
  },
  {
    id: 'message4',
    message: 'Thanks for saying that my friend.',
    userId: 'user4',
  },
  {
    id: 'message5',
    message: 'Hey buddy, what is up?',
    userId: 'user4',
  },
];

const getMessages = () => messages;
```

and what i want to do is basically on click allow the `messages` key value to be changed to an empty string `onclick` so that i get rid of the displayed messages without getting rid of the object so that i can later `push` new messages into these key values.

I started to write this but i seem to be missing something..

```
const clearBtnFunction = () => {
  messages.splice(1, '');
};
```

i'll be calling the event listener on my main.js file so i'm not super worried about that part yet. I just want to know the proper syntax for replacing the key value in the array if thats possible.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `splice()`. The arguments are `start, deleteCount, replacement1, replacement2, ...`. You seem to be missing either the start or count. And you're replacing an object with a string.

Comment: What do you mean by "the messages key value"? Do you mean IDs like `message1` and `message2`?

Comment: Show the desired result of the function.

Comment: What is key value? I dont see anything with a name of key. Maybe you want to use a dictionary and use `message1`,`message2` for the keys and use { message, userId } as the value

Comment: sorry my terminology still needs a little work. I'm wanting to take the value of `message:` and replace it with an empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
const clearBtnFunction = () => {
  messages.foreach( ( message ) => {
      message.message = "";
  });
};
```

or with a for loop

```
const clearBtnFunction = () => {
  for( let i =0; i < messages.length; i++) {
      messages[i].message = "";
  }
};
```

Comment: unfortunately eslint will not allow me to use a foreach loop on this

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i opted for. I placed this function, not in the messagesData.js but in the messages.js where i'm building the domstring

```
const clearBtnFunction = (e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const messages = message.getMessages();
 messages.splice(0, messages.length);
 messageBuilder(messages);
};
```

Comment: your splicing the whole array? Why not just have a new array or clear the array with myArray = []; Your objects are no longer in the messages array.